# How it is possible to filter sentences in an array by another array of words?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

Task

Build a service that provides content filtering for our chat application.
The service should listen to a firebase reference child “/messages” for the incoming messages. For each message that is written to this child you will need to filter the message and replace words with “*” from the ”/words” reference child in the firebase DB.

Part 1 -  List all messages at /messages on screen.

Part 2  - List all words at /words on screen.

Part 3  - Write an algorithm to change words from the /words list to **** if they appear in any message from /messages.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
      words: [],
      filterMessages: [],
    };
    console.log(this.state.messages, this.state.words);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const messages = firebase.database().ref().child('/messages');
    const words = firebase.database().ref().child('/words');
    console.log(messages, words);
    const messagesArray = [];
    const wordsArray = [];
    messages.on('child_added', snap => {
      messagesArray.push(snap.val());
      this.setState({
        messages: messagesArray,
      });
    });
    words.on('child_added', snap => {
      wordsArray.push(snap.val());
      this.setState({
        words: wordsArray,
      });
    });
  }

  filterByWords = () => {

  };

  filterData = (data) => data.filter(this.filterByWords);

  renderListItem = (data) => data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index}>{item}</li>
    )
  });


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {console.log('render', this.state)}
        <ul className="defaultList">
          {this.renderListItem(this.state.messages)}
        </ul>
        <button
          className="filterBtn"
          onClick={() => this.filterData(this.state.messages)}
        >
          filter
        </button>
        <ul className="filterList">
          {this.renderListItem(this.state.filterMessages)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `Array.filter` and `Array.includes` are your friends here. Filter the sentence array by checking for existence in the banned words array.

Comment: Yep) i understand, but i dont know how filter word in offers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const messageWords = message.split(" ");
    const newWords = words.map(word => messageWords.includes(word) ? "*".repeat(word.length) : word);
```

That could be a general idea of what would work - depends on what your data looks like.

Basically for each message you need to split that message into words so that you can compare the /words to an individual messages words. Then its just a matter of finding if a message contains a word using Array.prototype.includes. If there is a match you return "*" multiplied by the length of the word, otherwise just return the word;